# Vertx run task 100 times and analyze result

Tags: java, concurrency, vert.x

I'm wondering how I can write program on Java using Vertx to run task(call to remote server) 100 times concurrently, wait when all 100 remote calls are finished or failed and then analyze the result.
I have some ideas but I'm not sure that it is efficient. 
For now I'm just using random.nextBoolean instead of remote server call.

I've read that I can create 100 verticles and listen by event bus for responses, but All this I need to run periodically so I will have some problems with Identifying which response was to which request.

I don't know how to build it right.

If you have some suggestions you welcome.
Very appreciate for any help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    WorkerExecutor sharedWorkerExecutor = vertx.createSharedWorkerExecutor("netstate-pool");
    List<Future> works = new ArrayList<>(100);
    Random random = new Random();

    IntStream.iterate(0, operand -> ++operand).limit(100)
            .forEach(itaration -> {
                works.add(Future.future());
                sharedWorkerExecutor.executeBlocking(future -> {
                    future.complete(random.nextBoolean());
                }, false, asyncResult -> {
                    works.get(itaration).complete(asyncResult.result());
                });
            });

    CompositeFuture.join(works).setHandler(result -> {
        if (result.succeeded()) {
            System.out.println(works.stream().map(future -> (Boolean) future.result()).filter(res -> res.equals(true)).count());
            System.out.println(works.stream().map(future -> !(Boolean) future.result()).filter(res -> res.equals(true)).count());
        } else {
            System.out.println(works.stream().map(future -> (Boolean) future.result()).filter(res -> res.equals(true)).count());
            System.out.println("fail at least one");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this example can get you started:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import io.vertx.core.CompositeFuture;
import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpClient;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServer;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.Async;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.TestOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.TestSuite;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.report.ReportOptions;

public class HttpConcurrencyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        TestSuite suite = TestSuite.create("HttpConcurrencyTest");

        Integer requestCount = 100;
        Integer responseDelay = 200;
        Integer timeAllowed = 5000;
        String title = String.format("Sends %d HTTP requests with a response delay of %dms each within less than %dms.", requestCount,
                responseDelay, timeAllowed);

        suite.test(title, context -> {

            Async async = context.async();
            HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
            Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            server.requestHandler(request -> {
                vertx.setTimer(responseDelay, event -> {
                    request.response().end("ok");
                });
            });
            Integer port = 8181;
            server.listen(port, ar -> {
                context.assertTrue(ar.succeeded(), "Server not started");

                HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();
                List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int count = 0; count < requestCount; count++) {
                    Future future = Future.future();
                    futures.add(future);
                }
                CompositeFuture.all(futures).setHandler(result -> {
                    context.assertTrue(result.succeeded());
                    server.close();

                    Long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
                    context.assertTrue(duration < timeAllowed, duration + " >= " + timeAllowed);

                    async.complete();
                    System.exit(0);
                });

                futures.stream().forEach(future -> {
                    vertx.runOnContext(action -> {
                        client.getNow(port, "localhost", "/", result -> {
                            result.bodyHandler(body -> {
                                future.complete();
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });

            });
        });
        suite.run(new TestOptions().addReporter(new ReportOptions().setTo("console")));
    }
}
```

Inside the `CompositeFuture.all(futures)` you can analyse the results of all the individual calls.

Code can also be found ready to run here: https://github.com/thokari/vertx-http-concurrency